# how to upload and execute a file in django then show the result?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to build a web application using Django These are the flow I'm planning to execute:

Page1 - User upload file to be executed using the upload button and then press execute button.

Page2 - execute the Python code and show the result.

i have tried the upload part but i still need help in the execution and the show of the result .

Comment: You know that it is trivial to write a program that will attempt to delete all files from the root down right?

Comment: What if user try to delete your server files with this script? You need some sandbox method to do something like this. To isolate user uploaded code from the system and other users. Or use some js library to execute python code in browser.

Comment: This question is much broader than it might initially seem to you. We could potentially answer with some hack that uses subprocesses and say that it is done but that would be insecure, building a website that executes arbitrary code in a secure manner is not simple and needs proper designing. I'm voting to close this since if you just want to execute code without any sandboxing you'll probably find many duplicates of that (Not listing any here to prevent inadvisable use) and if you do want to have sandboxing it lacks focus.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.